# is there any harmful effects of loading page often by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, load

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#profil_resmi').load('profile.php?randval=' + Math.random());
        },1000);
    });

</script>
```

my code is above.is there any overwhelming effect over browser or over current page of using this code in my page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You will hammer your server;
- If requests take longer than 1s to succeed (which is not unrealistic), then you will have more and more simultaneous connections as time goes on.

  You should ensure that previous requests have finished (either by success or failure) *before* starting a new one.

Comment: The last point is extremly valuable - instead of setting interval, settimeout, and in the success callback of the request set the timeout again

Comment: @Darhazer: You won't get updates every 1s that way, but certainly something needs to change yes. I'd probably just set a flag in the success callback, and check for the flag in the `setTimeout` trigger before doing owt.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of requests. Use it really only in case when you know that you'll need it. **It could make some problems when your server is overloaded/there are many users online**

Answer (score 0):

If you have many users opening this page the web server could potentially be hammered with lots of HTTP requests. So make sure that this server is capable of responding to all of them in a meaningful time. You could increase the time between those requests if you encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request each second is too much! How often the data is actually changed? Better implement [long pooling / Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to watch out for memory leaks in some browsers, particularly older ones.  Lots of DOM manipulation is one place where some older browsers had leaks.  I don't know if your particular case would trip on this or not, but it is something to check out in IE7/IE8 in particular and any other old browser you intend to support.